# Problems importing Causal Impact in Colab when using Google's TPU's

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory, python-import, importerror

Whenever I try to import Causal Impact when using Google's TPU's I get the following error:

[image]

I find it weird, because I am able to import it when using whenever I´m not using any type of hardware accelerator. Does anybody knows what may I be doing wrong?

P.S: I've got the 0.2.6 version of the package installed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to stem from the `numba` module. Upgrading `numba` then installing `causalimpact` worked for me, see the code block below.

```
!pip install --upgrade numba
!pip install causalimpact
```

`from causalimpact import CausalImpact`